# CSS: Second <div> does not get scroll bar

Tags: html, css

I'm making a small website. The background is filled with a picture, say, a map. On the right is an overlay on top of the picture. The overlay has a title, and a list below it.

Now I cannot get to have the list get a scrollbar if it is too large to fit in the screen.

I do not want the page to scroll: the background fills out the screen 100%. I do not want the complete overlay to scroll (comment out the first CSS comment to get this). I also do not know the size of the title beforehand - if I knew that, it would be easy (simply comment out the second comment in the CSS, and hey presto, works). I can go the long way, and have javascript watch the title panel size, but I'd rather have a plain CSS/html solution.

Any ideas?

Code:

```
<html>
<style>
div {
    font-size:1.5em;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:green;
}
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
.panels {
    position:fixed;
    top:50px;
    right:50px;
    bottom:50px;
    /* overflow:auto; */
}
.list {
    /* position:absolute;left:10px;right:10px;top:150px;bottom:20px; */
    background-color:white;
    overflow:auto;
}

</style>

<div class='panels'>
    <div class='header'>Some title or other</div>
    <div class='list'>
        <ul>
            <li>Entry</li>
...lots of entries...
            <li>Entry</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</html>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/95ajc0us/

Answer (score 1):

Add height:100% for the second div.

```
 .list {
    background-color:white;
    overflow:auto;
    height:100%;
  }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/95ajc0us/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I need the .list to be inside the .panels - with your change, the .list drops out of it.

Answer (score 0):

`scroll` is missing because you have a `fixed` `panel`, which will prevent the `div` from scrolling

you need to `fix` `header`, not `list`

```
.header{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
}
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/95ajc0us/1/)

[**final edit**](http://jsfiddle.net/95ajc0us/10/)  (*updated fiddle on Suresh Ponnukalai answer*)

Comment: I see what you mean, but in this solution I do not have an overlay - and my background map will not be visible.

Comment: @Niels : i just gave you a markup...you can adjust the dimensions of it...give me a little more detail about your markup and we'll havea solution :)

Comment: Well, you're saying that I do not get a scroll bar because my panel is fixed - but if I enter 'scrollbar:auto' I do get a scroll bar - only, for the complete panel, which is not what I want. I want to have the scrollbar in the .list <div> only. What I want is a background map filling the complete screen, with no page scrollbars, and on top of that an overlay with two areas: one the title, and one a list of options below it. the list area must fill the remaining height, with an optional scroll bar if too big.

Comment: @Niels : ok...wait :)

Comment: Well, this solution has 'height:86%', which is not working if I have a very big header. As stated, I do not want to specify the size of the header - it can be big or small.

Comment: @Niels : is your data dynamic? i assume you need media query or jQuery..because thats the best CSS can produce for you! :)

Comment: Yes, thanks for the suggestion - It looks like you are right and I need a more complex solution.

Comment: @Niels : no probs, i suggest you go with media query, they are simpler in comparison to JS or jQuery! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish the list should scroll down in case of more entries.

Just write down :

```
ul{
overflow:scroll;
height: 200px;
}
```

for your UL(Unordered list)

Please feel free to ask again we are not on same page..
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but if the list is long, I want it to span the complete height of the overlay - as per CSS, I have some small margins top/bottom. In your solution the list height is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

you have fixed the html and body position.

instead fix the position of header

```
.header{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
```

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/95ajc0us/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to adjust the top and bottom properties to taste:

```
div
{
 font-size:1.5em;
 padding:10px;
 background-color:green;
}
html, body
{
 height:100%;
 margin:0;
}
.panels
{
 position:fixed;
 top:50px;
 right:50px;
 bottom:50px;  
}
.list
{
 position:absolute;
 left:10px;
 right:10px;
 top:150px;
 bottom:20px;
 background-color:white;
 overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Comment: Um, as I said in the question, I want the header not to be restricted by height - which is what the 'top:150px' is doing.

Comment: Yes you did, which is EXACTLY why you should NEVER use the CSS I provided.